# Backbone.js: Call a function, which has parameters, from fetch success

Tags: backbone.js

I am defining a backbone.collection from my database. I would like to execute a function which has a callback in the success callback. How could I do it?

```
 function firstFunction(callback){
  callback()
}

myCollection = new Backbone.Collection
myCollection.url = /collection
myCollection.fetch({
  success: firstFunction(callback)    
})
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `success: function() { firstFunction(callback) }`?

Comment: You could also have `success: callback`. If the `firstFunction` all that it does is to call `callback()`, then you could omit it entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute some callback function on success you can just subscribe on 'sync' event in your View (if you call fetch there):

```
var view = new Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.yourFirstCallback);
  },
  yourFirstCallback: function() {
    //code of yourFirstCalback here
    this.yourSecondCallback();
  },
  yourSecondCallback: function() {
    //code of yourSecondCallback
  }
});
```

But actually this is not very clear what do you exactly want.

If you want to use 'success' property, you can do it by two ways.
1. You can specify callback function directly for 'success':

```
youCollection.fetch({
  success: yourFirstCallback
});
function youFirstCallback(collection, response, options) {
  //do your staff here
  yourSecondCallback();
}
function yourSecondCallback() {
  //do your staff here
}
```

2. You can execute your callback function in 'success' callback:

```
youCollection.fetch({
  success: function(collection, response, options) {
    //what you want to do first is here
    yourSecondCallback();
  }
});
function youCallback() {
  //do your staff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JakeBlues and sorry because I think I didn't explain so well my question. I want to execute one function in the success callback and when this first finishes to call the callBack. I want to be sure that it is executed exactly after the first function finishes. Do you think is it possible in the way you explained to me?

Comment: You can do it in any way I have already explained above. I have updated my answer for you.